# Select rows based on multiple columns that are later than a certain date

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
# create an array of 5 dates starting at '2015-02-24', one per minute
rng = pd.date_range('2021-07-29', periods=5, freq='D')
rng_1  = pd.date_range('2021-07-30', periods=5, freq='D')
rng_2 = pd.date_range('2021-07-31', periods=5, freq='D')
df_status = ['received', 'send', 'received', 'send', 'send']
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Date_1': rng_1, 'Date_2': rng_2, 'status': df_status }) 
print(df)
```

I would like to print out all the rows if at least one column contains a date that is equal to, or at least 2021-08-01. What would be the most effective way to do this?

I have tried to do this with the following code, however, I get the following error:

```
start_date = '2022-08-01'
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
mask = (df['Date'] >= start_date | df['Date_1'] >= start_date | df['Date_3'] >= start_date)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'Timestamp' and 'DatetimeArray'

Thank you in advance.

Adjusted dataframe:

```
df = {'sample_received': {1: nan,
2: nan,
3: '2022-08-01 20:31:24',
4: '2022-08-01 20:25:45',
5: '2022-08-01 20:41:22'},
'result_received': {1: '2022-08-01 16:25:33',
2: '2022-08-01 13:25:36',
3: '2022-08-02 09:45:34',
4: '2022-08-02 09:52:59',
5: '2022-08-02 08:22:45'},
'status': {1: 'Approved',
2: 'Approved',
3: 'Approved',
4: 'Approved',
5: 'Approved'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `any` inside `apply`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: any([x[col] >= pd.to_datetime('2021-08-01') for col in df.columns]), axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please see my edit. Would this answer also still work the same way, or does it also need any adjustments?

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `any`:

```
df[df.ge('2021-08-01').any(1)]
```

output:

```
        Date     Date_1     Date_2
1 2021-07-30 2021-07-31 2021-08-01
2 2021-07-31 2021-08-01 2021-08-02
3 2021-08-01 2021-08-02 2021-08-03
4 2021-08-02 2021-08-03 2021-08-04
```

intermediate:

```
df.ge('2021-08-01').any(1)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

##### using only the date columns

filtering by name (`Date` in the column name):

```
df[df.filter(like='Date').ge('2021-08-01').any(1)]
```

filtering by type:

```
df[df.select_dtypes('datetime64[ns]').ge('2021-08-01').any(1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please see my edit. Would this answer still work the same way, or does it need any adjustments?

Comment: @TimS see update

Comment: thank you for the adjustments. Could you also make it work on the last version that I uploaded? This version replicates the original dataset as much as possible. So that if either the date in the sample_received column, or the date in the result_received column is equal or higher than 01-08-2022. Thanks : )

Comment: @TimS pass the list of column names manually: `df[df[col_list].ge...]`

Comment: Unfortunately processing of the column names in the list does not work. Do you have any other suggestion on the once more adjusted dataframe that I just oploaded?

Comment: Sorry but the requirements are unclear (you're not supposed to change the question many times). If you can convert your columns to datetime, then the "*filtering by type*" approach will work. Otherwise, maybe open another question on how to select types, which is not really the focus of your original question ;)

Comment: Will do that, thanks.

Comment: I have just tried to use all your answers to get the necessary output, but it does not work. Even if I use both columns in which the date is included, such as in df[df[col_list].ge...], I get the green checkmark, but still all the rows are included. It does not filter only the rows which mentioned august 1st onwards.